How can I keep .net in-memory cache up-to-date in separate projects?
I have a project that can be considered as a gateway in terms of flow and I have more than one project working behind it. A request falls to my project that works instead of the gateway and I pull the data requested in the request from another project with rest requests and keep it in the in-memory cache in the gateway project. When the same request comes to the gateway project again, I can get some information I need from the data I cached. My problem is this. With the first request, I sent a request to another project and received the data and cached it, but I want the data I cached to stay up-to-date. I don't want to do the cache job again by sending a request to another project every time a request comes. How can I keep this cache up-to-date in my project where the gateway is in place?

I assume that using an out-of-process cache that both services talk to (Redis, etc) is out of the question?

It's definitely so

Additionally, I would like to point out that I have pulled this data from the db in my other projects and that it is data that I would not want to pull constantly.

Have your different projects (proceses?) that need to have the "same" cache content talk to each other using some IPC mechanism. However, that will be no easy job (at the least you have to live with the fact that those cache instances can never be exactly in sync/up-to-date with each other). You'll probably be much better off using an out-of-process cache.

I don't have such a possibility. I just need to cache the data I will receive from another service in my gateway service and keep this cache up to date.
